# IEEE 1588 PTP Clock Source in STM32H743

Tags: ethernet, stm32f7, stm32cubemx, ptpd, stm32h743

I'm trying to get `PTP` timestamp on `STM32H743 Nucleo` board. There is no proble with `LwIP` and ethernet driver so far except for `PTP`. I followed the instruction( 58.9.7 Programming guidelines for `IEEE 1588 timestamping`) on reference manual (`RM0433`) as follow.

```
  CLEAR_BIT(heth->Instance->MACIER, ETH_MACIER_TSIE);
  SET_BIT(heth->Instance->MACTSCR, ETH_MACTSCR_TSENA);
  WRITE_REG(heth->Instance->MACSSIR, 20);
  WRITE_REG(heth->Instance->MACTSAR, 894784853);    // 2^63 / 20 / 480M
  SET_BIT(heth->Instance->MACTSCR, ETH_MACTSCR_TSADDREG);
  while(READ_BIT(heth->Instance->MACTSCR, ETH_MACTSCR_TSADDREG));
  SET_BIT(heth->Instance->MACTSCR, ETH_MACTSCR_TSCFUPDT);
  WRITE_REG(heth->Instance->MACSTSUR, 0x01);
  WRITE_REG(heth->Instance->MACSTNUR, 0x02);
  SET_BIT(heth->Instance->MACTSCR, ETH_MACTSCR_TSINIT); // If one-step timestamping is required follow reference manual
  // TODO: configure pps
```

However, System time seconds register (`ETH_MACSTSR`) does not count and just loaded initial value in System time seconds update register (`ETH_MACSTSUR`). In reference maual there is no clear information about clock source for `PTP`. In `STM32F7`, there is a clock path for `PTP` as in image below in `CubeMX` clock configuraton page.

[image]

However there no clock path for `PTP` in `STM32H7` as in image below.

[image]

Am I missing something about to get system time from the registers `ETH_MACSTSR` and `ETH_MACSTNR`?

Comment: I was interested to hear which clock source you ended up using for the 1588 timestamping block. I am tentatively hoping to input a clock to OSC_IN and then select HSE which generates sys_clk and then use sys_clk to generate rcc_hclk1. Also is the clock that you use variable? i.e. changed on the fly?

Comment: we use ptp clock within ETH_MAC

Comment: Thanks @iertuk for getting back to me. Sorry when you said ptp clock it wasn't too clear to me. Referring to the image that you had in your question, I was wondering which of the clock(s) were you sourcing to the ethernet MAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the `Sub-second increment register (ETH_MACSSIR)`. The value to be incremented is stored in `high word` of the register as in the image below. so the value has to be shifted by 16.

[image]

Everything runs as expected when changed the value as follow.

```
WRITE_REG(heth->Instance->MACSSIR, ((uint32_t)20)<<16);
```